# Getting heading value -1 in getCurrentPostion method in geoloaction

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

I am using navigator.geoloaction.getCurrentPostion method for getting current latitude and longitude and I am getting heading value as -1 in iOS whereas in android it working fine

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        alert("postion12345........6" + JSON.stringify(position.coords.heading));
     })
```

In android, I am getting the heading value but in iOS it is -1
Can anyone help how to get heading value in iOS using that method.

Comment: heading <= 0.0f || heading > 10.0f Means location accuracy is too low or you are sitting indoor area. Please test your app in open area, Hope it will work fine

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani ok I will check in open area once